# how to let php process a constant in form

Tags: php

I am trying to create a PHP page, which reads the database first and then make changes to it.  And I will use PHP Form.

I know that `<input name=''>` could let the users type in data and proceed to the next page, but how could I process the existing data in the database and process it to the next page?

I am using:

```
<?php on = mysqli_connect("localhost", "name", "password", "db");
    $drink = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE P_class='drink'");
        while ($set1 = mysqli_fetch_array($drink))
            {
            $id = $set1['P_id'];
            echo "<form action = 'checkoutprocess' method = 'post'>Product: ".$set1['P_name']."     ";
            echo "In Stock: ".$set1['P_qty']."<br/>";
            echo "Quantity: <input type='text' name='qty'><br/><input type = 'submit' value = 'SUBMIT'/></form>";
            }
        echo "</div>";
        ?>
```

So here I am trying to process the `$id` to the checkoutprocess page, but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Are you trying to do an edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting the ID as a hidden element to the form...

```
echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "item_id" value = "' . $id . '">';
```

On the next page, look for `$_POST['item_id']`.

On a side note, you will still have to validate the posted hidden elements on the server, since its pretty trivial to construct a form that will post to your script that allows me to edit those hidden values.

Comment: but i dont know why my process page not work. My code is `<?php
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $qty = $_POST['qty'];
$con = mysql_connect ("localhost", "name", "password", "db");
 $sql = "INSERT INTO Temp (id, qty)
 VALUES
 ('$id', '$qty')";
 mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 
 header('Location: http://html');

 mysqli_close($con);
?>`   Actual the problem is the value can't insert into table, but the codes works, no error occur

Comment: please update your answer with what actually happens with your process script